# How do I use a different port for an nginx proxy on docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have an two containers running via docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: me/web
    container_name: web

  nginx:
    image: me/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ../nginx:/etc/myapp/nginx
```

My nginx container copies in a new `default.conf` from the mapped volume from the `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cp /etc/myapp/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

My custom `default.conf` looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.website.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web/;
  }
}
```

With this configuration everything works as expected. After starting with `docker-compose` I can then navigate to http://my.website.com and access the `web` container instance properly.

However, now I want to change my port to something other than the default `80`, such as `81` for example:

```
services:
  ..

  nginx:
    image: me/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - '81:80'
  ..
```

Now this no longer works. Whenever I visit http://my.website.com:81 I get:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> my.website.com refused to connect.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The other weird part is that if I use `localhost` rather than `my.website.com`, everything works just fine on port 81. Ex:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web/;
  }
}
```

Navigating to http://localhost:81 works correctly.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I configure nginx to something other than `localhost` (my domain) and proxy on a different port than 80 to my `web` container?

Comment: Are you sure the port 81 is open on `my.website.com` i.e. firewall rules are in place etc

Comment: @keith Wow, that was it. I had opened the port internally but forgot to open it at the external network layer as well. Total brain fart. Feel free to post as an answer and I will accept if you'd like.

Comment: OK, I've added an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that port 81 is open on my.website.com i.e. check firewall rules are in place etc